# how div object convert in to html

Tags: jquery

`$('#envelop .modalDialog div[id]')` this div return below data

```
<div id=​ "0001">​
    <ul>
        <li>Automatic XML Generation</li>
        <li>STF Generation</li>
    </ul>
</div>​,
<div id=​ "0002">​
    <ul>
        <li>Document management system</li>
        <li>PDF And HTML Publish</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

div id=0001 and div=0002 is dynamically generated

so how can both div convert in to html using jquery or javascript

Comment: do you want the html markup for both these elements... do you want it as an array or single string... or do you just want the list of ids

Comment: i need out put below type

Comment: [
​
Automatic XML Generation
STF Generation
​
​,
​
Document management system
PDF And HTML Publish
​
​]

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9oata1k/1/ ?